# Enable automatic updates through play store

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to ask questions again about what to do for updating my android tablet application(tablet:Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 or HP Tablet) without asking user to install my update when the update is downloaded.

As I observed Tinder mobile app updates itself without asking me to install the updates, I am sure there is a way to do it in tablet. What I tried on my tablet was,

1. I published my app on Google Play(version 1)
2. I downloaded and installed it on tablet(Samsung and HP tablet android 4.4 kitkat).
3. I republished my app(version 2) on Google Play by changing only version number and versino code with everthing else the same such as User Permissions.
4. It's been a day since my version 2 was already published.
5. I kept my tablet on and wifi on, plugged for a day.

No updates have been installed through Google Play. 
Is it because it is a tablet application? Tinder app I have is a my cellphone app. Tablet I am using is not registered with any cellphone provider like Verizonwireless, Sprint, or T-mobile.

Would you please help me with this issue? I even asked Google Play Developer to help me but they are really slow to respond.

Comment: Did you enable automatic updates on your tablet? A simple explanation could be that you have this enabled on your phone and disabled on your tablet.  You can't release an update of the other app to test that on your tablet, but you could make and test update a dummy app to try on your phone.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, I did enable automatic updates on Google Play Setting. I don't see any settings for automatic updates on tablet itself. Would you please advise me where to find it if I am forgetting this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

On my test, I was able to see my updates onto my HP tablet automatically from Google Play as some people confirmed with me.

It took me at least 1 day to 2 days to see that update however it turned out that it works~!!